# SQL Update Query returning error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Stock FROM Products WHERE ID=" + ProductID + ";", conn); //run the database query
OleDbDataReader cusReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //read the result of the query
cusReader.Read();           
ProductStock = (int)cusReader.GetValue(0);
cusReader.Close();
MessageBox.Show((ProductStock).ToString()); // checks that the form is being accessed and the SELECT query works

OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Products SET Stock=" + (ProductStock - 1) + "WHERE ID= " + ProductID +";", conn);

try
{
   if (cusReader.RecordsAffected > 0)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("no issue was experienced");
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("An issue occured when decreasing stock");
   }
   cusReader.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("An error occured in query.\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

The update query returns the "an issue occurred" message. The message box that shows the variable Productstock does return the correct value. Can anbody explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you even executing the update-statement?

Comment: You may want to call `ExecuteNonQuery` on `cmd1`. I guess that's what @Dirk meant.

Comment: the code that isn't working was copied word for word from an update query that worked perfectly, so I'm assuming I have

Comment: @peter.petrov yes, and of course also put a space in the query like you said in your answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to use `ExecuteNonQuery`

Answer (score 2):

Put a space here right before `WHERE` in `+ "WHERE ID= " +`

Also, make sure you call `ExecuteNonQuery` on `cmd1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Products SET Stock=" + (ProductStock - 1) + " WHERE ID= " + ProductID +";", conn);
```

Please use above command.

**Problem:** No space between stock value and where

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.It should work

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Products SET Stock=" + (ProductStock - 1) + " WHERE ID= " + ProductID, conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try update in *one go* (do not separate `select` and `update`: someone can modify the data *after* you've performed `select` but *before* you've started `update`), and then check rows affected. Make you sql being *readable* to avoid evident errors.

```
string sql = 
  // Parametrize your query or at least format it out: 
  $@"update Products
        set Stock = Stock - 1
      where Id = {ProductId} and
            Stock >= 1 -- added: you must have stock to decrease";

// Wrap IDisposable into using
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn)) {
  int affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  if (affected > 0) 
    MessageBox.Show("No issue was experienced");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("An issue occured when decreasing stock");
}
```